# Changing name servers locally - windows

Tags: windows, dns, local, nameserver

Is it possible to change the nameservers of a specific domain locally? (On windows)
I want to test a new nameserver setup before actually switching the domains dns.

I can redirect the domain in the "hosts" file, but i would like the whole DNS to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really change DNS for a domain at the OS level, but you can play around with the new server using `nslookup`.  Just run `nslookup` and enter the command `server a.b.c.d` (where `a.b.c.d` is the IP of your new server.  You can then enter names for the server to resolve and see the responses.

Comment: Thank you. Even though it's not the perfect solution, it does the trick.